# Are there any tools to circumvent flash video advertising?

Tags: browser, flash, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions, advertisements

I'm thinking about the kind of unskippable ads that play before your video starts. For what it's worth I'm using Firefox, but any solution would be interesting to hear about.

Comment: Just uninstall Flash? YouTube supports HTML 5. All the major browers support HTML 5 even IE9.

Comment: @Ramhound: the problem isn't youtube. Specifically, in my case, its www.lemonde.fr, but it could be any site with videos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AdBlock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) can remove the ads that play before youtube videos. It also removes the text ads (Adsense for instance) from flash videos.

You can even extend the add-on by writing your own custom filters to block specific ads if needed.

Comment: How would I go about writing my filter for a site not yet supported by Adblock? I know how to write filters for static elements, but I'm at loss in this case.

Comment: @Peltier - All websites are supported by Adblock Plus.

Comment: @Peltier I usually use Element Hiding Helper(http://adblockplus.org/en/elemhidehelper) and AdBlock Pop-up Addon. you can select custom elements on any webpage with Element hider and it'll create a filter for you automatically.

Comment: I'm talking about blocking ads that show before a video. Blocking the frame isn't going to cut it. And no, not all ads are removed by ABP.

Comment: Personally I have not tried blocking an Ad inside the video because for me the video Ads are blocked by default. You can try AdblockVideo (http://adblockvideo.com/index.html). More info available on LifeHacker (http://lifehacker.com/5833052/adblockvideo-blocks-ads-in-hulu-and-other-online-video-players)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work with the site I was interested in. I'll still mark your answer as accepted as you have answered my original question. Thanks!